# Optional arguments with few mandatory arguments

Tags: python

I am new to python and came across a problem.

I have to get a dictionary from the user via a function that has few elements (key-value). At the same time, if the user is not providing the dictionary, they can provide individual elements as arguments.

How do I check if user has provided `dictA`, if not, `src` `msg`. If the user doesn't provides either one of them, return an error back to the calling function.

Lets say:

```
def myfunc(dictA, src, msg, e=True)
```

where `dictA` is the dictonary and `src`, `msg` are arguements if the user didn't provide dictA.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't support them passing in `dictA` or the other arguments.  I would just have them pass in `dictA` as kwargs if that want to use that.  Then you can just check if the values have been there

New function prototype might be

```
def myfunc(src, msg, e=True)
```

And then usages could be

```
myfunc(a_source, a_msg)
```

Or

```
myfunc(**dictA)
```

This way your function will automatically check that those values are at least present.  And any additional value checking can be done on only one input

For example the following call would fail (without you needing to do anything else) because it would still be missing the positional argument of `msg`.

```
myfunc(**{'src': 'a_source'})
```

Similarly it will fail if you send too many positional arguments as well (i.e. passing in a positional argument and a kwarg via a dictionary)

Comment: The requirement is that someone can pass those values either via dictionary or through individual arguments.

Comment: They still can pass it in via a dictionary, they just need to break them out as kwargs `myfunc(**dictA)`

Comment: if this is a homework question, then either use `assert` to validate arguments or `raise` an exception.  otherwise I'd suggest you do as @sedavidw suggests, it's a much nicer API to program to